# Splitting a linked list into 2. not using fast and slow pointer method. (with a length function)

Tags: c, split

How would you go about creating a function that would split a the passed in source (that is a linked list) into two linked lists using a function that already gives me the length of the list. Assigning the   first   half    of the      source linked   list    to  frontRef    and second  half    to  it  to  backRef.

The best I can think of is a way to make a first half list but the back half is what puzzles me.

Something like this:

```
typedef struct Data_ {

     char *name;
     struct Data_ *nextData;    

}Data;
```

split in half:

```
void    split_in_half(Data  *source,    Data    **frontRef, Data**  backRef){
        Data* temp = source; 

        if(source == NULL || source->nextData == NULL)
                    return; //this just returns the source link list if it is empty or only one iteam
        int i;
        int half = (length(source)/2) // finds the halfway point using a length function that counts how many nodes are in a linked list

        for(i=0;i<=half;i++){ // will loop up to that halfway point
               strcpy(frontRef->name,temp->name); //copys the data in the linked list to the frontRef  
               frontRef = temp->nextData;//copying node 
               temp = temp->nextData; //traverses the linked list
             }
```

that would copy the first half but how would you get the second half?

```
   if(frontRef->nextData == NULL){
            backRef = temp->nextData;
            strcpy(backRef->name,temp->name);
            temp = temp->nextData;
   }
```

i could be be pretty off im just a beginner.

Comment: Have you tried to compile this?

Comment: Do you need the original list afterwards? If not, you just need to set `*backRef` to the `nextData` pointer of the middle node, set that `nextData` pointer to `NULL`, and set `*frontRef` to `source`.

Comment: Unless you're replicating nodes (and you're not), `strcpy` has no business being in this code. This exercise is about pointer management. And to answer your question on how you would get the second half, ask yourself how you would *reach* the first node in the second half of the list in the first place? The previous node (the last node in the first half) and its `nextData` is going to play some part in that *somehow*, since it is the *only* thing that references the desired node going in to all this.

Comment: at the beginning of your code you are losing the beginning of the list by writing this line `frontRef = temp->nextData;//copying node`.
and also `strcğu()` method is not necessary.